# Https File download in java

Tags: java, http, selenium-webdriver, https

I need to verify the contents of the word file that appears on the browser. So I downloaded the doc file. 
My download code is given below:

```
 private String downloader(WebElement element, String attribute) throws IOException, NullPointerException, URISyntaxException {         
        localDownloadPath = "c:\\downloads";
 fileToDownloadLocation = "https://xyz.abc.com/link1/docs/"+element.getAttribute(attribute);

        if (fileToDownloadLocation.trim().equals("")) throw new NullPointerException("The element you have specified does not link to anything!");
        fileToDownloadLocation = fileToDownloadLocation.replaceAll(" ","%20");       

        URL fileToDownload = new URL(fileToDownloadLocation);            
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
         HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)fileToDownload.openConnection();
        System.out.println(con);
        //for cookies management 
//        BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();   
        HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        LOG.info("Mimic WebDriver cookie state: " + this.mimicWebDriverCookieState);
        if (this.mimicWebDriverCookieState) {
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, mimicCookieState(this.driver.manage().getCookies()));
        } 

        //core downloading part
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(fileToDownload.toURI()); 
        LOG.info("Sending GET request for: " + request.getURI());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, localContext);
        this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        LOG.info("HTTP GET request status: " + this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt);
        File downloadedFile = new File(this.localDownloadPath + fileToDownload.getFile().replaceFirst("/|\\\\", ""));        
        if (downloadedFile.canWrite() == false) downloadedFile.setWritable(true);
        LOG.info("Downloading file: " + downloadedFile.getName());
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(response.getEntity().getContent(), downloadedFile);
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();

        String downloadedFileAbsolutePath = downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        LOG.info("File downloaded to '" + downloadedFileAbsolutePath + "'");

        return downloadedFileAbsolutePath;
    }
```

It is working for http site. It is even working for one https site. But when i try it for other https site, I get a error as follows:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.iso.mozart.test.ui.FileDownloader.downloader(FileDownloader.java:166)
    at com.iso.mozart.test.ui.FileDownloader.downloadFile(FileDownloader.java:59)
    at com.iso.mozart.test.pageobjects.SearchResultsPage.downloadAFile(SearchResultsPage.java:293)
    at com.iso.mozart.test.pageobjects.SearchResultsPage.searchByKeywords(SearchResultsPage.java:142)
    at com.iso.mozart.test.ui.MozartUITest.testMozart(MozartUITest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'QAWIN7VMP04', ip: '10.16.96.19', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
Command duration or timeout: 9.17 seconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'enparajuli', ip: '192.168.79.35', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=4c85c8d0-e184-44d9-aba1-e439c4d50b78, browserName=internet explorer, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=-1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, platform=WINDOWS}]
Session ID: 4c85c8d0-e184-44d9-aba1-e439c4d50b78
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:468)
    at com.iso.mozart.test.ui.common.driver.BrowserDriver.stop(BrowserDriver.java:666)
    at com.iso.mozart.test.navigator.impl.MozartNavigatorImpl.stop(MozartNavigatorImpl.java:67)
    at com.iso.mozart.test.ui.BaseTestCase.stop(BaseTestCase.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'QAWIN7VMP04', ip: '10.16.96.19', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'enparajuli', ip: '192.168.79.35', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I couldnot figure out what am I doing wrong. Could any one please help? 
Any sort of help is warmly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 introduced SNI support which is enabled by default. Certain misconfigured servers send an "Unrecognized Name" warning in the SSL handshake which is ignored by most clients, except for Java.

Try adding `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` to the Java command arguments and see whether it helps.

[From here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=582877397)

Within the downloader method, add `System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false")` and see whether it helps.

Comment: I only want to download the file. I cannot modify the server file. By the way that application is developed using dotnet.

Comment: @i82186 no need to modify the server file. You just need to add this parameter to your java command line that is launching the tests. Alternatively, set the property in the `downloader` method (see update).

Comment: I added this : System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false") in my downloader function. But still encountering the same error.

Comment: I installed the following java maven command in terminal:


clean install -DTargetEnvironment=P -DRemoteUrl=http://example.com -Dselenium.browser=2 -DRunArguments=All -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false